# How can I add minimum date validation check for DatePicker in Xamarin

Tags: c#, user-interface, xamarin, datepicker, xamarin.forms

I am having two `DatePicker` (named fromdate and todate) and a button (named as save).

By default, today's date will be populated in both the `DatePicker`. And I have added minimum date validation ( the user can select only today's or greater date.

If today's date is 30th May and the user selects 15th June from `fromdate` and clicked ok. Now the default today date is displayed in `todate`.
I want a validation like if the user selects 15th June in `fromdate` and click ok, then the `todate` should be populated with `fromdate`.

Answer (score 8):

This can be done by binding the MinimumDate of the toDate DatePicker to the FromDate property.

I don't know your code so I will give you an example:

Imagine you have a XAML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-YourProject" 
    x:Class="YourProject.YourClass">

    <StackLayout>
        <DatePicker Date="{Binding FromDate}" MinimumDate="{Binding FromMiminumDate}" />

        <DatePicker Date="{Binding ToDate}" MinimumDate="{Binding FromDate}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And you have a ViewModel like this:

```
public class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public YourViewModel ()
    {
        FromMiminumDate = DateTime.Today;
    }

    private DateTime _fromDate;
    public DateTime FromDate
    {
        get { return _fromDate; }
        set
        {
            if (_fromDate == value)
                return;

            _fromDate = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged (nameof(FromDate));
        }
    }

    private DateTime _toDate;
    public DateTime ToDate
    {
        get { return _toDate; }
        set
        {
            if (_toDate == value)
                return;

            _toDate = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged (nameof(ToDate));
        }
    }

    private DateTime _fromMiminumDate;
    public DateTime FromMiminumDate
    {
        get { return _fromMiminumDate; }
        set
        {
            if (_fromMiminumDate == value)
                return;

            _fromMiminumDate = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged (nameof(FromMiminumDate));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void NotifyPropertyChanged (string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (propertyName));
    }
}
```

This will make that every time you change the date selected in the FromDate Picker the MinimumDate for the ToDate Picker will be changed too.

And of course the XAML code behind will be as simple as:

```
public YourClass ()
{
    var VM = new YourViewModel ();

    InitializeComponent ();

    BindingContext = VM;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

So you have two DatePickers: fromDate and toDate.

You can add an attribute to your fromDate which is called "PropertyChanged":

```
<DatePicker
x:Name="fromDate"
PropertyChanged="FromDate_Changed"
/>

<DatePicker
x:Name="toDate"
/>
```

Now you can go in your xaml.cs file and add the following to the constructor:

```
public ItemsPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    fromDate.MinimumDate = DateTime.Now;
    toDate.MinimumDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Now with both DatePickers you have to pick a date which is not from the past.

Then you can create the method "FromDate_Changed" (if it has not been created automatically):

```
private void FromDate_Changed(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    toDate.MinimumDate = fromDate.Date;
}
```

Now everytime when you change the date from the fromDate picker, the minimum date from toDate will automatically change to the date you selected in fromDate.

I know this question is 2 years old, but maybe for the future if someone is looking for exactly that problem, he will find an easier solution.

Excuse my english please.